# How to make snapshot for new tables only

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

If there is a replication running for a large set of data, and I want to add one or more new tables, I normally add the articles to the replication and start the snapshot agent.

Since there's a lot of data, this takes a while, interrupting users that do the normal operations on the database.

Is there a way to have the snapshot agent create the snapshot data only for these new (empty) tables?

Answer (score 1):

There sure is. There are two settings on the publication that need to be set correctly to get the behavior that you want. allow_anonymous and immediate_sync must be set to false. You can change both with a call to `sp_changepublication`. Note that the tables needn't be empty for this to work.